# Ping ESP8266 NodeMCU w Raspberry Pi through WiFi

Tags: ping

A Raspberry Pi newbie here.

Here is my resume, LOL:
I have done numerous Arduino projects using the Arduino IDE in windows.
I am very familiar with C++.
I have the most basic level experience using the Linux terminal.

I have a CanaKit Raspberry Pi 4 4GB Starter PRO Kit - 4GB RAM.
I also have a HiLetgo 3pcs ESP8266 NodeMCU CP2102 ESP-12E Development Board.

I would like to ping the ESP8266 NodeMCU with my Raspberry Pi through a WiFi connection between them.
I do -not- want to do it through a hard wired connection between them.

Can someone please direct me to a website where I can find instructions on how to ping ping the ESP8266 NodeMCU with my Raspberry Pi through a WiFi connection between them?

I am trying to measure the latency between the ESP8266 NodeMCU and the Raspberry Pi while they are connected to each other through a WiFi connection between them.

My effort so far:

Until now I have gone through 2 YT tutorials that kinda started getting incohesive and confusing.
I also have done exactly what is said in the tutorial below just to establish some sort of connection between the RPi and the ESP8266 NodeMCU but I am getting an Arduino error.
https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry ... 8266-MQTT/
The Arduino code in the above website compiles fine but when I try to upload the Arduino sketch to the ESP8266 NodeMCU, it says that it is done uploading but it also says, "A fatal esptool.py error occured: Write timeout"

Comment: Your question appears to be about Arduino code - ask on an Arduino site. Even if someone was to try and answer your link does not point to any code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [ping](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping) is for. Eg.:

```
> ping 10.8.42.2
PING 10.8.42.2 (10.8.42.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.42.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.353 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.42.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.365 ms
^C
--- 10.8.42.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1036ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.353/0.359/0.365/0.006 ms
```

The `^C` is where I killed the process with ctrl-C, otherwise it will just keep going (you can specify a limited number of pings with `-c`).

That's not an ESP on the other end, but if it is connecting to wifi properly and not firewalled to prevent it (which I think is pretty unusual), it should reply.

Ping is a standard tool for sending [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) echo request packets.  It will already be installed on the Pi (otherwise `apt install iputils-ping`).